# subraction error

Tags: python, subtraction

I have a certain error in a speed testing program I have built in Python. My program works by taking a variable of 0, adding 1 and printing its value. It repeats this 10,000 times, and records how long this all takes. After the time is taken every 1,000 cycle, it is arranged into a graph, with the columns, "Cycles", "Time", and "Time between previous checkpoint". The time between the previous checkpoint remains normal until it comes to 5 and 6 thousand cycles. It would look like this;

[image]

Here is a snippet of the table code:

```
print("   4,000        %ss                  %ss" % (check4, check4 - check3))
print("|          |            |                                  |")
print("   5,000        %ss                  %ss" % (check5, check5 - check4))
print("|          |            |                                  |")
print("   6,000        %ss                  %ss" % (check6, check6 - check5))
```

As you can see, the results spike then dip. The problem is, they shouldn't. It wouldn't make sense that there can be a negative amount of time between two events. I've checked where the checkpoint variables are assigned and they are like this;

```
    elif(count == 4000):
        check4 = round(time() - start, 3)
        check4 -= 0.3
        Beep(825, 100)
        print("        %s        %ss" % (count, round(time() - start, 2)))
    elif(count == 5000):
        check5 = round(time() - start, 3)
        check5 -= - 0.4
        Beep(850, 100)
        print("        %s        %ss" % (count, round(time() - start, 2)))
    elif(count == 6000):
        check6 = round(time() - start, 3)
        check6 -= 0.5
        Beep(875, 100)
        print("        %s        %ss" % (count, round(time() - start, 2)))
```

There is either something I've overlooked because I'm looking for something else, or my method is at fault. I've only come here as a last resort, I've been slaving over this on and off for at least 3 months.

If anyone could find what is causing this value anomaly, please could they respond.

Comment: Why are you performing those weird subtractions from each `checkN` variable?

Comment: Also, go learn about lists. Numbered variables are really error-prone and clumsy.

Comment: The question of @user2357112 is good. But please also note that you have a negative sign in front if the `0.4` in `check5`.

Comment: Thinking about it now, lists would also be helpful. I know how to use them now, but when I first started this project some time ago I didn't. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Also, I'm doing the subtraction to compensate for extra time caused by beeps played every 1000 cycles, for a duration of 0.1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second elif statement in your code snippet, it looks like you have a minus sign that should not be there:

```
elif(count == 5000):
        check5 = round(time() - start, 3)
        check5 -= [-] 0.4
        Beep(850, 100)
```

This makes your program add 0.4 rather than subtract, which seems to be the source of your error.

Comment: Thanks for your eagle eyes, I've been too frazzled to been able to look. Thanks for sharing

Comment: No problem! As a suggestion for the future, cleaner code is much easier to debug. Doing this sort of thing with a loop and a list could shorten it to 5 or 6 lines, which is so much simpler to debug

Comment: I know I know, but this program is weird because as I worked on it, I would get better I got until things like tables and line graphs with %s placeholders mixed in with unhelpful methods like 10 separate variables instead of lists. And yeah a loop seems more helpful than an if statement for 1, 2, 3k cycles etc